# install4j: Different installation paths for different components

Tags: install4j

I have 2 installation components, and I need them to be installed in different locations (and the user should be able to change them), but the installer only ask for one path for both.

Is there any simple way to change that or should I create custom forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Files->Define Distribution" step, you have to add new roots for the two installation components and add their files below these roots. Set the root directory names to installer variables, say `${installer:componentOneDir}` and `${installer:componentTwoDir}`.

Then you need a custom for screen with two "Directory chooser" form components whose "Variable name" properties are set to "componentOneDir" and "componentTwoDir".